# How do I keep track of the height in an array of objects and switch elements accordingly to the height?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, vue.js, multidimensional-array

I got the following array of objects. The array is dynamic, so entries can be added, deleted but also edited (and thus the height will change). I'm using Vuejs as my frontend and got a watcher on the height, so every time the height changes, the function `correctPage` gets called.

```
let pages = [
  //This is page 1.
  [
    {
      mainCol: [
        { height: 83, entry: 1 },
        { height: 120, entry: 2 },
        { height: 66, entry: 3 },
        { height: 79, entry: 4 },
        { height: 94, entry: 5 },
        { height: 48, entry: 6 },
      ]
    },
    {
      secondaryCol: [
        { height: 81, entry: 1 },
        { height: 56, entry: 2 },
      ]
    }
  ],
  //ONLY add this index if the height in one of the columns exceeds 500. 
  //This will represent page 2, if the height on the first index exceeds 500.
  [
    {
      mainCol: [
      ]
    },
    {
      secondaryCol: [
      ]
    }
  ],
]
```

Now, the idea is that whenever the height in of the columns (either `mainCol` or `secondaryCol`) exceeds `500`, the last entry gets spliced and a new index (and thus a new '`page`') is added to the pages array.

***The Problem***

My problem is that, although this is easy with 1 or 2 pages, it gets a hell of a lot trickier when there are 3, 4 or maybe even 5 pages. Because say there are 4 pages, if an entry is deleted on page 1, all the pages have to be updated, and there is a good chance that some entries of page 2 have to be spliced onto page 1, some entries on page 3 have to be spliced onto page 2 and so forth.

The approach I got now, contains tons of `if` and `if-else` statements and will not be suitable when the pages array gets larger. I'm not looking for a full fletched method that does everything for me, I'm looking for ways to approach this problem and techniques I can apply to solve it and pretty much 'keep track of the height and switch elements accordingly'.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Keep all entries in a single array. Then create a pages array dynamically based on that by iterating over all elements; keep track of the height and simply increase the page index and reset the height if it exceeds 500 otherwise.

Comment: Here's a code example: https://jsfiddle.net/zegay8ox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it took me a few days but I've implemented something similar into my application. Cheers :) @ChrisG